# Laravel: orWhereHas() disables where()?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to get all users who have a related row in the table `addresses` or in the table `institutes`. In addition, I want that `modeIN` should be equal to `MT`. I thought the following query would do that, but it does not work:

```
$users = User::whereHas('addresses')
          ->orWhereHas('institutes')
          ->where('modeIN', '=', 'MT')
          ->get()
          ->pluck('modeIN');

dd($users);
```

There are still users listed where `modeIN` is not equal to `MT`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Look at the query that's actually being generated, and the AND and OR combinations that you're actually building.... I think you'll find that it's `HAS ADDRESSES OR (HAS INSTITUTES AND modeIN = 'MT)`, rather than the `(HAS ADDRESSES OR HAS INSTITUTES) AND modeIN = 'MT'` that you expected

Comment: @MarkBaker since I have not set any braces it looks to me just like `HAS ADDRESSES OR HAS INSTITUTES AND modeIN = 'MT`. Whats the default logic how Laravel reads this?

Comment: The use of an OR is setting the braces for you..... look to the SQL that's being generated to execute the query if you don't believe me

Comment: Note that in standard SQL, AND has operator precedence over OR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't check this right now, but does something like this fix it?

```
$users = User::where('modeIN', 'MT')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->has('addresses')
              ->orHas('institutes');
        })
    ->pluck('modeIN');
```